# Could not resolve type name: Utility.HttpContextPerRequestStorage following WFFM install

Tags: wffm, webforms

I'm trying to install WFFM into Sitecore XP 8.1.

Following installation, the WFFM options appear in the desktop as expected. However, if I then do a clean and rebuild in Visual Studio, I then get the following error whenever I try to access any page on the site/in sitecore:

Could not resolve type name: Sitecore.Form.Core.Utility.HttpContextPerRequestStorage, Sitecore.Forms.Core (method: Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.CreateFromTypeName(XmlNode configNode, String[] parameters, Boolean assert)).

I then have to roll back all changes in order to bring the site back up - when I do this, the WFFM option is still present in my desktop menus, but then disappears again when I sync with Unicorn.

Can anyone enlighten me on this? I'm very new to Sitecore (picking up a project from someone else), and there seems to be no documentation for if things go wrong like this...

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

When you directly set up your IIS site to use your folder where the Visual Studio solution placed it can happen because of the **Rebuild**. Rebuild means cleaining up your bin folder and only take the assemblies which are in your Visual Studio project.

So if the **Sitecore.Form.Core.dll** is not used in your project then the **Rebuild** removes it. If you setup the site like this then you should only **Build**.

I suggest to you to setup a different root folder for your IIS and do a publish from **Visual Studio** to the clean Sitecore instance.

Here is a good article how to setup Sitecore with **Visual Studio** project - https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/developing/developing_with_sitecore/set_up_sitecore_and_visual_studio_for_development.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that I had been given the wrong version of WFFM for the version of Sitecore I was working with - annoyingly I am currently blocked from downloading packages myself, and it was only thanks to another developer that this was spotted.

So apologies for such a basic error - and thanks to Tamas for the article link, very handy for a beginner like myself.